# Spring can't find mapping for HTTP-request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a simple web-application, which allows users create topics and comment it. The idea was, that after starting a topic, user is redirected to this topic's page.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView create(Locale locale, Model model)
    {
         Topic newTopic = new Topic();
         logger.info("HomeControlller: Create");
         List<Tag> tagList = newTopic.getTagLict();
         Hashtable modelData = new Hashtable();
         modelData.put("newTopic", newTopic);
         modelData.put("tagList", tagList);

         return new ModelAndView("create", modelData);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveNewTopic(@ModelAttribute("newTopic")Topic topic, BindingResult result, Model model)
    {
         validate(topic, result);
         // Go to the "Show topic@ page
         return "redirect:details/"+service.saveTopic(topic);       
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/details/(topicId)", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView details(@PathVariable(value="topicId") int id)
    {
            logger.info("HomeControlller: Details: Found a method");        
            Topic topicById = service.findTopicByID((long) id);
            logger.info("HomeControlller: Details: Performing redirect");
            return new ModelAndView("/topic/", "model", topicById);
     }


}
```

But after creating topic i'm receiving error **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/simpleblog/details/9] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'**. And I can't understand what is wrong, because the HTTP-requests are mapped with annotations. And it works with **create()** and **saveNewTopic()** functions, but don't work with the **details()** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for a path variable is `{foo}`, not `(foo)`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/details/{topicId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView details(@PathVariable(value="topicId") int id)
```